# Trying To Create New Wordpress Database Table

Tags: database, wordpress

Just trying to create a new database table on plugin activation.
For the love of life I cannot figure out why this will not work.

```
function super_simple_photo_activate() {
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix."super_simple_photo_options";
if ($wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE '.$table_name) != $table_name) {
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$table_name.'(
        thumbs_max VARCHAR(3),
        image_max VARCHAR(4),
        image_quality VARCHAR(3),
        PRIMARY KEY  (id))';

    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);

    add_option("super_simple_photo_db_version", "1.0");
}
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'super_simple_photo_activate');
```

I've spent at least 5 hours tinkering with this but with no luck, no error either on activation.

**What did the trick** - id INTEGER NOT NULL - thanks t.thielemans

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$table_name.'(
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        thumbs_max VARCHAR(3),
        image_max VARCHAR(4),
        image_quality VARCHAR(3),
        PRIMARY KEY  (id))';
```

Comment: Watch out: I had to put the `$table_name` in quotes for `SHOW TABLES LIKE`. The code you posted did not work for me otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your create table syntax is wrong, should be:

```
 $sql = 'CREAT TABLE '.$table_name.'(
-----
 $sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$table_name.'(
```

Edit: Define your primary key

```
 $sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$table_name.'(
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        thumbs_max VARCHAR(3),
        image_max VARCHAR(4),
        image_quality VARCHAR(3),
        PRIMARY KEY (id))';
```

Bit of extra info on SQL from W3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Comment: Thanks! Very embarrassing that I missed that... Correction applied but still no luck.

Comment: Try this, this worked for me, with out `id INTEGER` the primary key function did not work.

Answer (score 19):

Try this code

```
register_activation_hook ( __FILE__, 'on_activate' );

function on_activate() {
    global $wpdb;
    $create_table_query = "
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$wpdb->prefix}table1` (
              `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
              `name` text NOT NULL,
              `address` text NOT NULL
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $create_table_query );
}
```

Comment: Ratnakar       What is 'ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' for?

Comment: It seems IF NOT EXISTS isn't needed if you're using dbDelta - if the table already exists it'll compare the schema and update it instead of overwriting the whole table. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-database-tables-maintaining-the-database--wp-28455

Comment: You definitely should remove IF NOT EXISTS from the example because it leads to a bug - if $create_table_query is being changed, dbDelta doesn't update the table because of it.